# How to load the external URL (text) in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load external URL in a div without using iframe/object/load tag. In this external site which is JSP there is only a text in  section as output. For example just number: 50

```
<html><body> 50 </body></html>
```

Here is what I already used:

```
$("#divName").html('<object type="text/html" data="https://external-site/index.jsp">');
```

And it work, but as you can see below, there is some problem with: height. (Only only the middle one uses the script)

Screen 1:
[image: Screen 1]

So added some height and width values, and it looks better... But still its a little too height, and I can't go lower.

```
$("#divName").html('<object type="text/html" width="35px" height="35px" data="https://external-site/index.jsp">');
```

Screen 2:
[image: Screen 2]

Same with:

```
    function loadSite(url,id){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data='+url+' width="35px" height="35px"></object>';
}
```

I can't do it with jQuery .load function, because of CORS problem.
It should be easy, because it's only text in external URL site, but I just looking on sites and cannot find good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this ? Probably get method will work.

```
function loadSite(url,id){
$.get( url, function(response) {  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = response; });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, $.get, thank you @Fatihd !
But there is still a problem with CORS. Now it only work in localhost with plugin in Chrome, and only work one link
There is a screen what I talking about: https://i.imgur.com/KJFzYvt.png
In another browser (Opera) I've only got info, and function not working:
`Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://external-site/index.jsp with MIME type text/html.`
Any more suggestion?

Comment: There was an CERT_INVALID_ERROR on screen, now with plugin all sites work, but without it no

Comment: ok. the only way is object. you can try object-position: ; and i hope that you can minimize the area of object with this css property .

Comment: I'll try something with CORS, if not, need to back to object-position...

Comment: I have it on WAS, and just added CORS filter in my every app, and deployed it on every server that I want to request... and finally it working. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try the load() function. http://api.jquery.com/load/

$("#divName").load("https://external-site/index.jsp");

Comment: Yup, work same as Faithids answer, but there is still problem with: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. I can't add it to header, and it need to work without cors plugin

Comment: enable cross-origin HTTP requests  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*  to allow requests from everywhere.